# I’m confused about how Whatsapp backs up data in iPhone

Tags: icloud

In Settings > (my name) > iCloud > iCloud storage: I can see “Whatsapp messenger: 12.8 MB”

In Settings > (my name) > iCloud > iCloud storage > Backups > (My iPhone) > Whatsapp: 86 MB”

What’s the difference between these two?

Answer (score 2):

The first shows you how much data, that has accumulated by using WhatsApp, is currently stored on your phone. That is chats, photos, videos and audio messages that have been send and received.

The second one is the Backup that can be created through WhatsApp->Settings->Chats->Chat Backup. The reason the Backup is larger than your „normal“ app data might be that WhatsApp stored multiple Backups (either from multiple devices or older ones from the same device). Another reason might be that you backed up WhatsApp on an old device or reset your current one after backing up WhatsApp, so your backup contains more data than you accumulated by using WhatsApp after switching/resetting your device.

Again, the first is the data that is currently used by WhatsApp, the second one is the backup and its data is not accessible/used by WhatsApp unless you restore the backup.

Answer (score 0):

I have never backed it up, but I have sort of the same problem. 
In my case it's 670 mb of storage according to iPhone setting vs 4,45 GB according to whatsapp itself. 
I can access all the 4,45 GB of movies / pictures in my whatsapp conversations.

Don't know why iPhone storage doesn't seem to calculate correctly. But the amount of data that you are using according to whatsapp itself (under settings), is the correct one.